# Retrieve the result of a scalar sql function in php

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-function

I have a scalar sql function which returns integer value either 1 or 0 . It is working perfectly in sql server management studio. I am executing the function in php like below.

```
$getuserloginfo = mssql_query("SELECT dbo.prtl_checkforce_pwd($userID) AS result");
```

I need to get the value returned from the function .
ie

```
if(getuserloginfo==1){ } like this.
```

But when I tried to check the `getuserloginfo`,it is showing `Resource id #79` rather than 1 or 0. If am wrong how to get the value of my function in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

*Returns a MS SQL result resource on success, TRUE if no rows were returned, or FALSE on error.*

Then you should use:

`$version = mssql_query('SELECT @@VERSION');
$row = mssql_fetch_array($version);
return $row[0];`

source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php

Comment: Thanks...I was enough stupid that I didnt think about this way